# Можно ли рекламный рабочий (не тестовый) баннер AdMob вставлять в бета-версию приложения?

Tags: android-studio, admob, реклама

Т.е. рабочий баннер (не тестовый) в не рабочую бета-версию приложения?

Спасибо advance! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это не версия подготовленная к релизу для пользователей, то Google рекомендует использовать [заглушку](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) во избежании блокирования.

Comment: Извините, я не знаю что такое деплойная версия... У меня бета-версия, т.е. еще не рабочая

Comment: Прошу прощения за сленг, деплойная - это как раз та которую вы выпускаете для всех пользователей.

Comment: Т.е. в распространяемую через Google Play Console бета версию можно вставлять только тестовый баннер (ad test from AdMob)? Переспрашиваю для подстраховки )))

Comment: Если этой версией пользуются реальный пользователи, а не только вы, можно вставлять обычную рекламу. Если же вы постоянно загружает приложение во время тестирования и разработки (только вы) гугл может посчитать что вы пытаетесь заработать просматривая рекламу.

Comment: Я же четко сказал если у вас есть пользователи в приложении и вы показываете им рекламу - все в полном порядке. Если же это закрытая бета версия для вас и еще пары тройки разработчиков - то нужно использовать заглушку. Теперь вы понимаете что я имею в виду?

Comment: Да. Спасибо... А как грамотно подключить не тестовый баннер? Шаги? Переводим приложение в Рабочую версию, И тут же обновляем версию с уже подключенным не тестовым баннером?

Comment: @YuriK, что значит подключить не тестовый банер? Разница лишь в id баннеров. Подключаются они совершенно одинаково. Пока вы тестируете собственное приложение используете ключи которые предоставлены в статье на сайте Google (которую я кидал в ответе). Когда вы собираете приложение которым уже будут пользоваться люди, заменяете эти id на ваши.

Comment: Можно по-подробней... Что это за заглушка и как ее использовать? По ссылке все английском,  неохота ошибиться... Добавляем строку типа .addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232") и можно выкладывать бета-версию???

Comment: @YuriK, в данном случае вам лучше задать новый вопрос. Так как с реализацией я Вам помочь мало чем смогу.